# Keycloak Admin Client with Quarkus?

Tags: java, keycloak, resteasy, quarkus

I'm trying to instantiate a `org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak` object in my Java web app that uses Quarkus as its application framework.  I've done this successfully in the past on applications that have been deployed to Wildfly, but it's not translating to Quarkus as expected.  My factory class that instantiates the `Keycloak` object looks like this:

```
Keycloak kc = KeycloakBuilder.builder().serverUrl(authServerURL).realm(realmName).clientId(clientID)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret).username(adminUsername).password(adminPassword).build();
```

However, when I attempt to call the factory method, I end up with this exception:

```
14:10:08 ERROR [io.undertow.request.io] Exception handling request 87ecb4cf-b4b3-4e2b-9e54-7427c88f9897-1 to /api/v1/tests/accounts/create: java.lang.InstantiationError: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.newRestEasyClient(Keycloak.java:70)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.<init>(Keycloak.java:57)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder.build(KeycloakBuilder.java:147)
    at com.myapp.test.security.keycloak.KeycloakClientFactory.createKeycloakClient(KeycloakClientFactory.java:75)
    at com.myapp.test.security.keycloak.KeycloakAdminClient.init(KeycloakAdminClient.java:58)
    at com.myapp.test.security.keycloak.KeycloakAdminClient_Bean.create(KeycloakAdminClient_Bean.zig:80)
    at com.myapp.test.security.keycloak.KeycloakAdminClient_Bean.get(KeycloakAdminClient_Bean.zig:202)
    at com.myapp.test.security.keycloak.KeycloakAdminClient_Bean.get(KeycloakAdminClient_Bean.zig:61)
    at com.myapp.test.rest.services.test.TestRS_Bean.create(TestRS_Bean.zig:320)
    at com.myapp.test.rest.services.test.TestRS_Bean.create(TestRS_Bean.zig:179)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:80)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache$CacheFunction.lambda$apply$0(ComputingCache.java:99)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.getValue(ComputingCache.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:25)
    at com.myapp.test.rest.services.test.TestRS_Bean.get(TestRS_Bean.zig:163)
    at com.myapp.test.rest.services.test.TestRS_Bean.get(TestRS_Bean.zig:405)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:355)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:367)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$1.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:222)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$1.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:219)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder$2$1.create(ArcRecorder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.runtime.QuarkusConstructorInjector.construct(QuarkusConstructorInjector.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.createResource(POJOResourceFactory.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.createResource(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:62)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:252)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:153)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:363)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:156)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:238)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:65)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:270)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:116)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:113)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:475)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:82)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:290)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:669)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:224)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1395)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)

14:10:08 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.error-response] Setting error code 500 for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /api/v1/tests/accounts/create delegate io.undertow.vertx.VertxHttpExchange@2bcf472c}: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.setStatusCode(HttpServerExchange.java:1108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:295)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:116)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:113)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:475)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:82)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:290)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:669)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:224)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1395)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
```

My assumption is that this is related to a Resteasy version mismatch or some other dependency issue.  However, I'm at a loss as to how to fix this.  Any advice?

**UPDATE 1:**  Full stack trace now included

Comment: Could you copy the full stacktrace? Don't you have a cause below that? Could you also give more information about Keycloak version and Quarkus version?

Comment: Adding *quarkus-rest-client* should fix it. But what is the actual requirement behind creating Keycloak Admin client ? Perhaps we can provide a standard OIDC client support for registering the users, clients, etc

Comment: @GuillaumeSmet I've updated the question to include the full stack trace.  I am using Keycloak v8.0.1 and Quarkus 1.0.1.

Comment: @SergeyBeryozkin I have quarkus-rest-client listed as a dependency.  As to the requirement, I have a need to create user accounts programmatically without exposing the Keycloak admin APIs directly.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be fixed in Quarkus 1.4 ([release notes](https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-1-4-final-released/#keycloak-admin-client)).

That release added a new extension `quarkus-keycloak-admin-client` ([source code](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/master/extensions/keycloak-admin-client)).